# ERROR :The thread 0x4c0c has exited with code 0 (0x0). Exception thrown: read access violation. **this** was nullptr

Tags: c++, arrays, error-handling, access-violation

For one of my programming classes in c++, we are required to design a bool array class- including length and boolean array with memory allocation,
and I get error message -
**The thread 0x4c0c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: read access violation.
this was nullptr.**

it comes up when I try creating new array using **changeLength** method:

BOOL ARRAY H FILE

```
#ifndef BOOL_ARRAY_H
#define BOOL_ARRAY_H
class boolArray
{
public:
    boolArray() { array = { NULL }; length = 0; }
    boolArray(int len);//setting new array according users input
    void intialize(int len);//setting new array according users input
    void changeLength(int len);//create new array with new length
    
private:
    bool validIndex(int index);//check if the number is in the relevant range
    bool* array;
    int length;
};
#endif
```

BOOL ARRAY CPP FILE

```
boolArray::boolArray(int len)
{//ctor with parameter
    if (validIndex(len))//checking if the length is a valid number
        intialize(len);//set the new array
}
void boolArray::intialize(int len)
{//setting new array according users input
    length = len;//initialize length from user
    array = new bool[length];//memory allocation
    if (!array)//check if memory allocation succeeded
    {
        cout << "memory allocation failed!" << endl;//show message
        return;//go back
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        array[i] = 0;//set all cells false
}
void boolArray::changeLength(int len)
{//create new array with new length
    if (length!=0)//if array exists //ERROR HERE
        delete[] array;//free memory
    intialize(len);//set new array
}
bool boolArray::validIndex(int index)
{//check if the number is in the relevant range
    if (index >= 0 && index <= length)
        return true;//if it is returns true
    else//if not in the range
        cout << "please enter a valid number!" << endl;//message
    return false;//return false
}
```

MAIN USING BOOL ARRAY CLASS---

```
boolArray* array;
int len;//new array length
        cout << "enter size of array " << endl;
        cin >> len;
        array->changeLength(len);
```

Debugger:
[image]
THANK YOU!

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: note i've added an image of debugger  @SamVarshavchik

Comment: Sam knows what a debugger looks like. What you need to do with the debugger is step through the code while you keep an eye on the variables you are using. In this case you need to answer the question, "Why is `this` `NULL`?" To do that you work your way through the program to find where `this`  became `NULL` and then figure out how it happened from what you observed getting there. Sometimes this takes a couple restarts of the debugger and paying more attention to what's going on earlier in the program. The bug is often nowhere near where the program crashes.

Comment: u can be more gentle about it, and  i dont know what is `this` thats y I posted it @user4581301

Comment: `this` is the instance variable all non-`static` member functions have. When you invoke a member function on an object, that object shows up inside the function as `this`. A detailed discussion of `this` will come early in any non-fraudulent C++ programming text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, you're kind of fortunate `array` was null. It could have been anything right down to grandma's house because you forgot to initialize it and point it at a valid instance of `boolArray`.

```cpp
boolArray* array; // uninitialized pointer
int len;//new array length
cout << "enter size of array " << endl;
cin >> len;
array->changeLength(len); // Crom only knows what array points at.
```

The most direct solution is to not use a pointer at all

```cpp
boolArray array; // no need for a pointer here
int len;//new array length
cout << "enter size of array " << endl;
cin >> len;
array.changeLength(len);
```

but I'd prefer

```cpp
int len;//new array length
cout << "enter size of array " << endl;
cin >> len;
boolArray array(len); // no need to resize.
```

Then you need to go fix the bug David Schwartz highlighted--It's far, far nastier--and this one:

```cpp
boolArray::boolArray(int len)
{//ctor with parameter
    if (validIndex(len)) //there is no length to validate against. 
                         // It hasn't been set yet.
        intialize(len); // length isn't set until in here
}
```

Checking the length of an array access before you build the array isn't useful, so I'd just remove it.

```cpp
boolArray::boolArray(int len)
{//ctor with parameter
    intialize(len);
}
```

And a warning: This class does not observe [the Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and cannot be copied safely.

Comment: k got it ,already fixed what David Schwartz mentioned, genaraly speaking I need it to be able to change its size(thats what memory allocation is for) , to my knowledge I don't have to initialize it  (ctor already did it) @user4581301

Comment: The constructor for a pointer doesn't do anything. All you get is a variable you can use to point at an object of the named type or a type that inherits from the named type. If you forgo the pointer, then you have an instance of that type and that will be constructed.

Answer (score 0):

```
array = new bool(length);//memory allocation
```

You meant `new bool[length]`.